# Stylus ends batch execution

Tags: windows, node.js, batch-file, windows-shell, stylus

I am currently trying to write a batch file to build my project in Windows.  The project is built with Stylus.  Stylus was installed with node.js and the -g flag

Whenever I run my batch file with the stylus command, no commands after the stylus call are executed.  It's like the completion of the stylus call forces a window close, even though running the command by itself does not close the window.

Here is my script:

```
set sourcedir="d:\Projects\Travnet\Web\source"
set destdir="d:\Projects\Travnet\Web\package"

::clean up the lackage dir
rmdir /q /s %destdir%
md %destdir% 

:: Duplicate all images for the package
xcopy %sourcedir%\assets\img\* %destdir%\img\ /y


::compress the stylus css
::-c is the source, -o is the output dir
if not exist %destdir%\css md %destdir%\css
stylus -c %sourcedir%\assets\styl -o %destdir%\css
::type %destdir%\css\* > %destdir%\css\styles.css
copy /b %destdir%\css\* %destdir%\css\styles.css

pause
```

Neither the copy command nor the pause command are being executed.  If I comment out the stylus command, they are executed.  The stylus command is outputting the files, so I am at a loss.

Does anyone kinow why stylus execution forces my script to end execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stylus` is most likely a batch file. You have to call other batch files with `call`, otherwise control won't return to the calling batch:

```
call stylus -c ...
```

Comment: As I'm sure you suspected, that was my issue.  Thanks for helping a newb!

Comment: This is something that quite frequently appears, especially with tools written in a language that requires an interpreter. The developers usually think that supplying a batch file is enough so that you can save the Java call but it brings problems within batch files, then :)